# Shared lock on a shared file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, locking, file-locking

Can we use both `fcntl` locking and `flock` locking (not simultaneously) on a shared file descriptor, if we want to share a lock between threads/processes?

Comment: What do you mean by _to share a lock_?

Answer (score 0):

`fcntl` locks are per-process locks. So you cannot "share locks" between processes, but you can between threads of one process.

`flock` locks are per-file table entry. So if one process opens a file and then `fork`s one of more times, each process' copy of the file descriptor will manipulate the same lock. (I don't think this is a very useful feature, though.)